# CSS attribute-value selector doesn't work if value contains hash # sign

Tags: css, css-selectors

Am using bootstrap LIKE dropdown menu with custom HTML5 attribute with `data-` as a prefix with a value starting from `#`, now for some reason I can't change this.

Here's the [script link](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/) (It's like this `<a href="#" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1">dropdown</a>`)

Now the issue is am using dynamic approach using PHP so child of an element changes often so I am not using `nth-child` so thought of using `attribute-value` selector but CSS doesn't accept if value contains `#`. Any workarounds for this?

```
<div data-demo="works">This works</div>
<br />
<div data-demo="#doesnt_works">This fails</div>
```

CSS

```
div[data-demo=works] {
    color: red;
}

div[data-demo=#doesnt_works] {
    color: green;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeq5W/)

Comment: You could potentially escape the character with a back-slash `div[data-demo=\#doesnt_works]` but this is untested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
div[data-demo='#does_work'] {
    color: green;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeq5W/2/)

Why it has to be quoted? Because `#` has special meaning in CSS. Quoting it hides that special meaning. The same effect could be approached using `"`: *`[data-demo="#does_work"]`* or by escaping `#` with `\`: *`[data-demo=\#does_work]`*

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the value in quotes `"`

```
div[data-demo="#doesnt_works"] {
    color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeq5W/1/